# Ratio between two numbers is 6:7 and the difference between them is 10. What are the two numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, systems-of-equations, ratio

I know the numbers are $60$ and $70$ but I got that by trial and error. Is there some other more logical way to do this problem?

Comment: Let the two numbers be $x$ and $y$. Assume $y$ is the larger number. You know $x/y = 6/7$ and $y - x = 10$. Can you solve this?

Comment: What about $-60$ and $-70$?

Comment: I never thought about that - you're right.. and even the simultaneous equations don't give that solution.  What does that mean?

Comment: Because, for the answers below, the initial equation should be $\left| x-y \right| = 10$. This gives two cases which requires more checking.

Comment: @Ritz if $y$ is the larger then either $\dfrac{x}{y}=\dfrac{6}{7}$ or $\dfrac{y}{x}=\dfrac{6}{7}$

Answer (score 6):

Call your two numbers $x$ and $y$. We have

$$x:y = 6:7 \implies x = \frac67y\\
\begin{align*}
\left|x-y\right| &= 10\\
\left|\frac67y-y\right| &= 10\\
\left|\frac67-1\right|\left|y\right| &= 10\\
\left|y\right| &= 70\\
y &= 70 \text{ or } -70\\
x &= 60 \text{ or } -60 \text{ respectively}
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

If $~\dfrac xy=\dfrac67~$ then $x=6k$ and $y=7k.~$ Indeed, $~\dfrac{6k}{7k}=\dfrac67.~$ Now, $y-x=7k-6k=k=10$.

Answer (score 0):

Call your two numbers $x$ and $y$, with $x$ being the bigger.

Then what you know can be expressed as:
$$
\frac{y}{x} = \frac{6}{7}
$$
and
$$
x-y=10
$$
That is a fairly easy system of equations to solve.